# Why isn't .replace working in Ruby Shoes?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am programming a little game based on the Fate RPG.  When the dice are rolled, I want to replace a string with another string using `.replace`.  I can get it to work in an isolated environment, but when I try to call the function from inside my program; it is as if Shoes is completely unaware of it.

Here is a simple example of how the function works that is executing correctly:

```
Shoes.app {
@push = button "Push me"
@note = para "Nothing pushed so far"
@push.click { @note.replace "Aha! Click!" }
}
```

And here is the relevant code from my game:

```
$results = para "Roll results go here.", :align => "center",
        :margin_bottom => 20, :margin_top => 8
@roll_button.click {
    current_roll = Die.new
    current_roll.roll
    current_roll.display_dice
    current_roll.tally
    current_roll.calc_total_roll(1) #param = skill level
    $shift  = current_roll.calc_total_shift(2) #param = opposition  
    $results.replace "Actual results"                       
    }
```

The `$results` block is in a different position in the code than the `@roll_button.click` block, but I have tries moving the click block to many different places in the code, and it didn't make a difference, so I don't think its relevant. Thanks.

*edit: Removed unnecessary '=' after `$results.replace`

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  In the interest of tidyness, I'm going to vote to close the question, because it doesn't have enough information for anyone other than you to be able to answer it.  But I'm glad you got your code to work--that's great!  Also, thank you for adding an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work.  The problem was the `.display_dice` function running just before `.replace`.  The offending code is here:

```
if $result1 == 1
        $die1.path = "dice_plus-1.png"
    elsif $result1 == 0
        $die1.path = "dice_nil-1.png"
    elsif $result1 == -1
        $die1.path = "dice_minus-1.png"
    else
        exit(1)
    end
```

I intended the `exit(1)` to let me know if my dice were receiving values they shouldn't, but it somehow prevented the next line of code from running, even though the flow of the program avoided those lines.  The fixed code is here:

```
if $result1 == 1
        $die1.path = "dice_plus-1.png"
    elsif $result1 == 0
        $die1.path = "dice_nil-1.png"
    else $result1 == -1
        $die1.path = "dice_minus-1.png"
    end
```

Comment: Ok next time consider `raise` instead of `exit` to give you an error you can see and possibly `rescue` from. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling a `replace` method, you're calling a `replace=` method which probably doesn't exist. Try it without the equals sign.

Comment: Ah, yes.  That was one of my increasingly desperate attempts to find any way to get that line of code to run.  I tried out every syntax I could think of since the official syntax seemed not to work.

Comment: Ok so what's your exact full error message? Add that to your question.

Comment: There was no error message, the code simply didn't execute.  But I found the cause.  Thanks for the help.